# Why am I getting these failures when trying to run npm install for an Angular project on macOS Catalina?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install

I have an existing angular project that was working just a couple of months ago and checked into git repo. I got a new macbook running Catalina, installed node and angular cli globally. After cloning the project from the git repo, I ran 'npm install' and the install fails. Can someone help me out with this problem? It seems deep into angular and node, and I'm kind of new to this. Here's the output:

```
user@mbp (master)-> npm install

    > grpc@1.23.3 install /Users/username/Development/angular/idea-portal/node_modules/grpc
    > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

    node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
    node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.23.3/node-v79-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz 
    node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.23.3 and node@13.6.0 (node-v79 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 

   CXX(target)Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver_registry.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver_result_parsing.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolving_lb_policy.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/retry_throttle.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/server_address.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/service_config.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel_pool_interface.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/deadline/deadline_filter.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/health/health.pb.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/fake_transport_security.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/local_transport_security.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/ssl/session_cache/ssl_session_boringssl.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/ssl/session_cache/ssl_session_cache.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/ssl/session_cache/ssl_session_openssl.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/transport_security_grpc.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/chttp2_server.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client/secure/secure_channel_create.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/insecure/server_chttp2.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/insecure/server_chttp2_posix.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/inproc/inproc_plugin.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/inproc/inproc_transport.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/client_load_reporting_filter.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/grpclb.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/grpclb_channel_secure.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/grpclb_client_stats.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/load_balancer_api.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/fake/fake_resolver.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/proto/grpc/lb/v1/google/protobuf/duration.pb.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/proto/grpc/lb/v1/google/protobuf/timestamp.pb.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/proto/grpc/lb/v1/load_balancer.pb.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/xds/xds.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/xds/xds_channel_secure.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/xds/xds_client_stats.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/xds/xds_load_balancer_api.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/round_robin/round_robin.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/dns_resolver_ares.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_ev_driver.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_ev_driver_libuv.o
      CXX(target)Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/message_size/message_size_filter.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/http/client_authority_filter.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/workarounds/workaround_cronet_compression_filter.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/workarounds/workaround_utils.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/plugin_registry/grpc_plugin_registry.o
      LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/libgrpc.a
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/alloc.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/atm.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/cpu_iphone.o
Release/obj.target/ares/deps/grpc/third_party/cares/cares/ares_parse_txt_reply.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ares/deps/grpc/third_party/cares/cares/ares_platform.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ares/deps/grpc/third_party/cares/cares/ares_process.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ares/deps/grpc/third_party/cares/cares/ares_query.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ares/deps/grpc/third_party/cares/cares/ares_search.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ares/deps/grpc/third_party/cares/cares/ares_send.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ares/deps/grpc/third_party/cares/cares/ares_strcasecmp.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ares/deps/grpc/third_party/cares/cares/ares_strdup.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ares/deps/grpc/third_party/cares/cares/ares_strerror.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ares/deps/grpc/third_party/cares/cares/ares_strsplit.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ares/deps/grpc/third_party/cares/cares/ares_timeout.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ares/deps/grpc/third_party/cares/cares/ares_version.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ares/deps/grpc/third_party/cares/cares/ares_writev.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ares/deps/grpc/third_party/cares/cares/bitncmp.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ares/deps/grpc/third_party/cares/cares/inet_net_pton.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ares/deps/grpc/third_party/cares/cares/inet_ntop.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ares/deps/grpc/third_party/cares/cares/windows_port.o
      LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/libares.a
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/address_sorting/deps/grpc/third_party/address_sorting/address_sorting.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/address_sorting/deps/grpc/third_party/address_sorting/address_sorting_posix.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/address_sorting/deps/grpc/third_party/address_sorting/address_sorting_windows.o
      LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/libaddress_sorting.a
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc_node/ext/byte_buffer.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc_node/ext/call.o
    ../ext/call.cc:104:53: error: no matching member function for call to 'Get'
        Local<String> current_key(Nan::To<String>(keys->Get(i)).ToLocalChecked());
                                                  ~~~~~~^~~
    /Users/username/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.6.0/include/node/v8.h:3594:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
      V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                              ^
    /Users/username/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.6.0/include/node/v8.h:3597:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
      V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                              ^
    ../ext/call.cc:681:27: error: no matching member function for call to 'Get'
        if (!op->ParseOp(obj->Get(type), &ops[i])) {
                         ~~~~~^~~
    /Users/username/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.6.0/include/node/v8.h:3594:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
      V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                              ^
    /Users/username/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.6.0/include/node/v8.h:3597:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
      V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                              ^
    2 errors generated.
    make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc_node/ext/call.o] Error 1
    gyp ERR! build error 
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
    gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.2.0
    gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.6.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/Users/username/Development/angular/idea-portal/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v79-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/Users/username/Development/angular/idea-portal/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v79-darwin-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v79"
    gyp ERR! cwd /Users/username/Development/angular/idea-portal/node_modules/grpc
    gyp ERR! node -v v13.6.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
    gyp ERR! not ok 
    node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.6.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/username/Development/angular/idea-portal/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v79-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/username/Development/angular/idea-portal/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v79-darwin-x64-unknown --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v79' (1)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/username/Development/angular/idea-portal/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1028:16)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.2.0
    node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.6.0/bin/node" "/Users/username/Development/angular/idea-portal/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
    node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/username/Development/angular/idea-portal/node_modules/grpc
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v13.6.0
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
    node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
    Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.6.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/username/Development/angular/idea-portal/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v79-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/username/Development/angular/idea-portal/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v79-darwin-x64-unknown --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v79' (1)
    npm WARN @angular/animations@8.2.14 requires a peer of @angular/core@8.2.14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.1 requires a peer of jasmine-core@>=3.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! grpc@1.23.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.23.3 install script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2020-01-16T20_34_52_595Z-debug.log

    Angular CLI: 8.3.22
    Node: 13.6.0
    OS: darwin x64
    Angular: 8.0.3
    ... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
    ... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
    ... router

    Package                           Version
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    @angular-devkit/architect         0.800.6
    @angular-devkit/build-angular     0.800.6
    @angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.800.6
    @angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.800.6
    @angular-devkit/core              8.0.6
    @angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.22
    @angular/animations               8.2.14
    @angular/cdk                      8.2.3
    @angular/cli                      8.3.22
    @angular/fire                     5.3.0
    @angular/material                 8.2.3
    @ngtools/webpack                  8.0.6
    @schematics/angular               8.3.22
    @schematics/update                0.803.22
    rxjs                              6.4.0
    typescript                        3.4.5
    webpack                           4.30.0
```

I'm running the latest version of macOs Catalina

I'm also getting a strange warning about core-js@3 when a creating a new project using 'ng new', but the new Angular project generated does compile and run:

```
username@mbp-> ng new test
? Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
CREATE test/README.md (1022 bytes)
CREATE test/.editorconfig (246 bytes)
CREATE test/.gitignore (631 bytes)
CREATE test/angular.json (3577 bytes)
CREATE test/package.json (1290 bytes)
CREATE test/tsconfig.json (543 bytes)
CREATE test/tslint.json (1953 bytes)
CREATE test/browserslist (429 bytes)
CREATE test/karma.conf.js (1016 bytes)
CREATE test/tsconfig.app.json (270 bytes)
CREATE test/tsconfig.spec.json (270 bytes)
CREATE test/src/favicon.ico (948 bytes)
CREATE test/src/index.html (290 bytes)
CREATE test/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
CREATE test/src/polyfills.ts (2838 bytes)
CREATE test/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE test/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
CREATE test/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE test/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE test/src/environments/environment.ts (662 bytes)
CREATE test/src/app/app-routing.module.ts (246 bytes)
CREATE test/src/app/app.module.ts (393 bytes)
CREATE test/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE test/src/app/app.component.html (25530 bytes)
CREATE test/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (1092 bytes)
CREATE test/src/app/app.component.ts (208 bytes)
CREATE test/e2e/protractor.conf.js (808 bytes)
CREATE test/e2e/tsconfig.json (214 bytes)
CREATE test/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (637 bytes)
CREATE test/e2e/src/app.po.ts (262 bytes)
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.

> fsevents@1.2.11 install /Users/username/Development/angular/test/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node

> fsevents@1.2.11 install /Users/jusername/Development/angular/test/node_modules/karma/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node

> fsevents@1.2.11 install /Users/username/Development/angular/test/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node

> fsevents@1.2.11 install /Users/username/Development/angular/test/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node

> core-js@3.2.1 postinstall /Users/username/Development/angular/test/node_modules/core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"


> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /Users/username/Development/angular/test/node_modules/karma/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> @angular/cli@8.3.23 postinstall /Users/username/Development/angular/test/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

npm WARN karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.1 requires a peer of jasmine-core@>=3.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

added 1443 packages from 1068 contributors and audited 19051 packages in 34.442s

23 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

    Successfully initialized git.
```

I'm not sure what's causing all of this. It seems the install of node and angular cli was successful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try removing 'node_modules' folder and then 'npm install' again.
2. Check  '.npmrc' configuration

Comment: check registry as the error is 404, you may have to check proxy setting

Comment: I tried all that. I have a feeling this has something to do with xcode command line tools vs node-gyp. It's so frustrating! Takes up so much time. I uninstalled xcode, reinstalled, did an update, etc. Still the same error

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. node-gyp doesn't currently support the latest nodejs (v13), so rolling back to v12 fixed it.